# Angularjs ng-show == Id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was sitting on an issue trying to figure it out and then unexpectedly did something that worked! :)

But I have no idea why it is working??

Would appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

**What I wanted to do was:** using Id values to determine whether the button should display or not, like :

> If Id == 1 button should be shown.
>
> and if Id >= 2 button should be hidden.

and I have another event where I toggle the Id's manually and the button Shows/Hides correctly as I change the values.

**HTML**

The thing that boggles me is `ng-show="S == ph[0].PhaseId"` because, in my explanation I said it should be determined with the Id's. and with this coding it does not (in my sense) show where it compares the value to the correct Id's.

```
 <button ng-if="ph" type="button" class="col button button-small button-dark" ng-init="showMe(ph);" ng-show="S == ph[0].PhaseId">
Check In
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $scope.showMe = function()
  {  
        $scope.S = true;
  }
```

Comment: If `ph[0].PhaseId` is `true`, then it'll show. What's so complicated in that? Also, you could as well do: `true === ph[0].PhaseId`. Use three `=`s.

Comment: It is because `ph[0].PhaseId` isn't the same value when it changes, it ranges from `1` too `7`. and only `1` should be true. there is no where in my coding where I say only `1` should be true? @cst1992

Comment: Non-zero values will be treated as `true`. You should use `===`, it's stricter type checking, and will break the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb just test the exact code you put inside an `ng-show` (or `ng-if` or `ng-hide`) and verify that in a certain condition is evaluates to `true`. In this case with `$scope.S = true` the expression `S == ph[0].PhaseId`evaluate to `true`. Why? Because `==` works a little different than in other languages, probably here you need `===`.

For example `true == 1;` evaluates to `true` but `true === 1;` evaluates to `false`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) a better reference.

Try to change `==` with `===`

Comment: Indeed, `==` checks only for equality, whereas `===` checks for both equality and type, e.g. `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question exactly but looking at the query, it seems that since you are calling `showMe()` initially, the value for your bool `S` will become `true`. Now for `1==true` it will return true while for any other value that will return false. So it shows up when `id` is 1 and gets hidden for any other value.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are using a non-strict comparison ('==') and types of the values are not being compared. true value is a 1 (basically), so true == 1 will return true, while true == 2 will return false. That's a pretty brief explanation, but that's how I see this :-)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the following in ng-show. when the value is 1 it shows otherwise it hides.

```
ng-show="ph[0].PhaseId"
```

Comment: what happens when the value is 2?

Comment: This only checks if `ph[0].PhaseId` is truthy

Comment: When value != 1, the condition is false. Hidden automatically

Comment: No, nothing is checking this against 1. As @Naigel said, what happens when the value is 2? It will show, because 2 is truthy. [A plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/psyqc3d84NqaKBPUYF4s?p=preview) to show it.